# how to build this json in php

Tags: javascript, php, json

im using php to send a push but my json object isent getting the way i want...

i need my json to be like this :

```
{
    "to": ["xxx"],
    "data": {
        "title": "dw",
        "body": "dw",
        "actions": [
            { "icon": "emailGuests", "title": "Candidatar-me", "callback": "app.emailGuests", "foreground": true},

        ]
    }
}
```

but im getting this instead :

```
  {
  "to": "xxx",
  "data": {
    "title": "dw",
    "body": "dw",
    "actions": {
      "icon": "send.ico",
      "title": "EMAIL GUESTS",
      "callback": "app.callbackName",
      "foreground": true
    }
  }
}
```

i am building my json like this :

```
$fields = array (  'to' =>   $row1['fcm_registered_id'] ,  
                    'priority' => "high",  
                    'data' => array("title" =>$titlepost, 
                                    "body"=> $msg, 
                                    "actions" => array('icon' => 'send.ico', 
                                    'title' => 'EMAIL GUESTS',
                                    'callback' => 'app.callbackName',
                                    'foreground' => true 
                                    )
                    ), 
                );
```

Comment: well, just look at it: your desired data structure has a first-level-fild called 'registration_ids' - so don't you think that *somewhere* you should **add that field** to your data structure? also - it has no 'to' field - so why did you think it's a good idea to add *that field* instead? the question suggests that you actually haven't tried *anything* to achieve the goal you described and instead want us to do it for you.

Comment: i tried ... its not the names i care about its the stracture ... that was only an example

Comment: well, you see the structure in your example. the value of 'registration_ids' is an array - so you should add an array there, not a single value....

Comment: my problem is with the actions field .. i dont know how to output it like that with the [ ] on the php ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `json_encode`converts non-numeric indexed arrays to objects. There is why you gets objects instead of array of objects. It's enough to wrap this array by another array. Here is fixed code:

```
$fields = array ( 
    'to' =>   array( $row1['fcm_registered_id'] ),
    'data' => array(
        "title" =>$titlepost, 
        "body"=> $msg, 
        "actions" => array(
                array(
                    'icon' => 'send.ico', 
                    'title' => 'EMAIL GUESTS',
                    'callback' => 'app.callbackName',
                    'foreground' => true 
                )
        )
    )
);
```

And here is working example: http://phpio.net/s/1n0e

Little note: try to use new array syntax: `[]` than old `array()`

Comment: perfects tks alot Piotr